# Finding $\cos(A+C)$ given that $A,B,C$ are angles in an acute triangle.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Given that $A,B,C$ be angles in an acute triangle.

If $(5+4\cos A)(5-4\cos B)=9$ and $(13-12\cos B)(13-12\cos C)=25$

find $\cos(A+C)$. 
I know $A+B+C=180^\circ$ and $\cos B=-\cos(A+C)$ and what next?

Comment: Have u tried equating the two values of $\cos B$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the challenging problem! I enjoyed working through it.

The [tangent half-angle substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution) works really well here. Let $a = \tan ({A\over 2})$, $b = \tan({B\over2})$, $c = \tan({C\over2})$ then $a,b,c > 0$ and

$$ \cos A = \frac{1-a^2}{1+a^2}, \quad \cos B = \frac{1-b^2}{1+b^2}, \quad \cos C = \frac{1-c^2}{1+c^2} $$

Substituting these into the given equations and simplifying we (eventually) get $$ a = 3b, \quad b = {1\over 5c}$$

Using the triangle relationship we also have 
$$ \tan \left( {A\over2} + {B\over2} \right) = \tan \left(90^\circ-{C\over2}\right) = \cot \left({C\over2}\right) $$
$$ \frac{a+b}{1-ab} = \frac{1}{c} $$
Thus
$$  \frac{4b}{1-3b^2} = 5b $$
$$ b^2 = {1\over 15}$$

Back-substituting gives
$$ \cos B = -\cos(A+C) = {7\over 8} $$

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$(5+4\cos A)(5-4\cos B)=9\implies \cos A=\frac{-4+5\cos B}{5-4\cos B}\tag1$$

Using $(1)$ and $$\cos C=\cos(180^\circ-(A+B))=-\cos(A+B)=-\cos A\cos B+\sin A\sin B$$ we get

$$(13-12\cos B)(13-12\cos C)=25$$$$\implies \sin A=\frac{15(1-\cos B)(4\cos^2B-7\cos B+4)}{\sin B\ (5-4\cos B)(13-12\cos B)}\tag2$$

Now using $(1)(2)$ and $\cos^2A+\sin^2A=1$, we get
$$\left(\frac{-4+5\cos B}{5-4\cos B}\right)^2+\frac{1}{1-\cos^2B}\left(\frac{15(1-\cos B)(4\cos^2B-7\cos B+4)}{(5-4\cos B)(13-12\cos B)}\right)^2=1,$$
i.e.
$$(-4+5\cos B)^2(1-\cos B)(1+\cos B)(13-12\cos B)^2+225(1-\cos B)^2(4\cos^2B-7\cos B+4)^2$$$$=(5-4\cos B)^2(1-\cos B)(1+\cos B)(13-12\cos B)^2,$$
Dividing the both sides by $1-\cos B\not=0$ gives

$$(-4+5\cos B)^2(1+\cos B)(13-12\cos B)^2+225(1-\cos B)(4\cos^2B-7\cos B+4)^2-(5-4\cos B)^2(1+\cos B)(13-12\cos B)^2=0,$$
i.e.
$$256\cos^5B-1632\cos^4B+3712\cos^3B-3762\cos^2B+1657\cos B-231=0$$

Trying $\cos B=\pm \frac{\text{(a divisor of $231$)}}{{(\text{a divisor of $256$})}}$, we get
$$(8\cos B-7)(4\cos B-1)(4\cos B-11)(2\cos B-3)(\cos B-1)=0$$
So, we see that it is necessary that $$\cos B=\frac 14,\frac 78$$

In the following, let us see if $\cos B=\frac 14,\frac 78$ are sufficient.

- For $\cos B=\frac 14$, we get $\cos A=-\frac{11}{16}\lt 0$ which is impossible since $A$ is acute. So, $\cos B=\frac 14$ is not sufficient.
- For $\cos B=\frac 78$, we get $\sin B=\frac{\sqrt{15}}{8},\cos A=\cos C=\frac 14,\sin A=\sin C=\frac{\sqrt{15}}{4}$. Here, we have $$\cos(A+B+C)=\cos(A+B)\cos C-\sin(A+B)\sin C=-1$$So, $\cos B=\frac 78$ is sufficient.

Therefore, the answer is
$$\color{red}{\cos(A+C)=-\frac 78}$$